# LINQ to CRM One to Many results without flattening

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I'm trying to use LINQ to CRM to get some data in a parent/child format.  It's a One to Many and I don't want the Child records flattening with the Parent.  Firstly is what I'm asking possible?

I do not have navigation properties and there will be many parents returned, in turn each parent will have many children.

I'm trying to avoid multiple queries, just fetching it in 1.

So I'm after:

So the parent has many Children and the children have some other lookup properties in other tables 1 to 1.

Parent
--Child + other info
--Child + other info

Parent
--Child + other info

Parent
--Child + other info
--Child + other info
--Child + other info

etc

I've tried getting the Details as a IQueryable first, then using that joined on the header:

```
var detailsOnly = (from det in db.details
                   join inc in db.Incidents on det.detOtherId equals inc.incidentid into incidentsLo
                    from subInc in incidentsLo.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   join cli in db.Accounts on subInc.accountid equals cli.accountid into accountsLo
                    from subCli in accountsLo.DefaultIfEmpty()

                   select new
                   {
                       det,
                       AccName = subAcc.name, 
                       AccRef = subAcc.accountnumber,
                       IncidentTicketNumber = subInc.ticketnumber,
                       IncidentKeyDescription = subInc.title,
                       IncidentMainContact = subInc.maincontactname
                    });

var query = from head in db.headers
            where head.IsDone == isdone & head.type == typeId & head.accountid == AccountId
            select new MyHeader(head)
            {
                MyDetails = detailsOnly.Where(md => md.det.detOtherId == head.headOtherId)
                .Select(d => new MyDetail(d.det)
                {
                    AccName = d.AccName,
                    AccRef = d.AccRef,
                    IncidentTicketNumber = d.IncidentTicketNumber,
                    IncidentKeyDescription = d.IncidentKeyDescription,
                    IncidentMainContact = d.IncidentMainContact
                }).ToList()
            };

var result = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Can you help out a bit with the code? I'm used to seeing AccountSet, IncidentSet, etc. Also is it just one level deep? i.e., give me all the parents that match some criteria and all the children for those parents? What is the purpose of calling `DefaultIfEmpty()` in the query? If the list is empty there is nothing to join on. I've using the CRM LINQ provider fairly extensively and would be happy to help but need more information.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like this is getting a real answer, so the best I can say is to execute the details collecting part, group it, then select the other parts from that.

```
var detailsOnly = (from det in db.details
                   join inc in db.Incidents on det.detOtherId equals inc.incidentid into incidentsLo
                    from subInc in incidentsLo.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   join cli in db.Accounts on subInc.accountid equals cli.accountid into accountsLo
                    from subCli in accountsLo.DefaultIfEmpty()

                   select new MyDetail(det)
                   {
                       AccName = subAcc.name, 
                       AccRef = subAcc.accountnumber,
                       IncidentTicketNumber = subInc.ticketnumber,
                       IncidentKeyDescription = subInc.title,
                       IncidentMainContact = subInc.maincontactname
                    }).ToArray();


var groupedDetails = detailsOnly.GroupBy(c => c.det.detOtherId);

var query = db.headers.Where(head => head.IsDone == isdone
                                     && head.type == typeId
                                     && head.accountid == AccountId);

var result = query.Join(groupedDetails, c => c.headOtherId, c => c.Key, (a, b) => new MyHeader(a) { MyDetails = b })).ToList();
```

I could be way off on that, but you see the gist. I don't think it's the *best* way, but I don't have any experience with LINQ-to-CRM so I don't know. Something like this should work, though. Better than nothing. There might also be syntax errors, because this hasn't been tested.